# TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization, scrapy

I just started programming Python. I want to use scrapy to create a bot，and it showed 
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable when I run the project.

```
import json
import codecs

class W3SchoolPipeline(object):

  def __init__(self):
      self.file = codecs.open('w3school_data_utf8.json', 'wb', encoding='utf-8')

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + '\n'
      # print line

      self.file.write(line.decode("unicode_escape"))
      return item
```

---

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from w3school.items import W3schoolItem

class W3schoolSpider(Spider):

    name = "w3school"
    allowed_domains = ["w3school.com.cn"]

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.w3school.com.cn/xml/xml_syntax.asp"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@id="navsecond"]/div[@id="course"]/ul[1]/li')

    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = W3schoolItem()
        title = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        link = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        desc = site.xpath('a/@title').extract()

        item['title'] = [t.encode('utf-8') for t in title]
        item['link'] = [l.encode('utf-8') for l in link]
        item['desc'] = [d.encode('utf-8') for d in desc]
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Traceback：

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
2017-06-23 01:41:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing       {'desc': [b'\x
e4\xbd\xbf\xe7\x94\xa8 XSLT \xe6\x98\xbe\xe7\xa4\xba XML'],
 'link': [b'/xml/xml_xsl.asp'],
 'title': [b'XML XSLT']}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File  
"c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-p
ackages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "D:\LZZZZB\w3school\w3school\pipelines.py", line 19, in process_item
    line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + '\n'
File 
"c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\_
_init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File 
"c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\e
ncoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File  
"c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\e
ncoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
File      
"c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\
json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
  TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 50):

You are creating those `bytes` objects yourself:

```
item['title'] = [t.encode('utf-8') for t in title]
item['link'] = [l.encode('utf-8') for l in link]
item['desc'] = [d.encode('utf-8') for d in desc]
items.append(item)
```

Each of those `t.encode()`, `l.encode()` and `d.encode()` calls creates a `bytes` string. Do not do this, leave it to the JSON format to serialise these.

Next, you are making several other errors; you are encoding too much where there is no need to. Leave it to the `json` module and the *standard* file object returned by the `open()` call to handle encoding.

You also don't need to convert your `items` list to a dictionary; it'll already be an object that can be JSON encoded directly:

```
class W3SchoolPipeline(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('w3school_data_utf8.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(item) + '\n'
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

I'm guessing you followed a tutorial that assumed Python 2, you are using Python 3 instead. I strongly suggest you find a different tutorial; not only is it written for an outdated version of Python, if it is advocating `line.decode('unicode_escape')` it is teaching some extremely bad habits that'll lead to hard-to-track bugs. I can recommend you look at [*Think Python, 2nd edition*](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) for a good, free, book on learning Python 3.

Answer (score 39):

Simply write `<variable name>.decode("utf-8")`.

For example:

```
myvar = b'asdqweasdasd'
myvar.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This is not possible in every time, In the given example, you can do it

```myvar = b'asdqweasdasd'```


But what if 

```myvar = random.randbytes(50)```

Answer (score 8):

I was dealing with this issue today, and I knew that I had something encoded as a bytes object that I was trying to serialize as json with `json.dump(my_json_object, write_to_file.json)`. `my_json_object` in this case was a very large json object that I had created, so I had several dicts, lists, and strings to look at to find what was still in bytes format.

The way I ended up solving it: the `write_to_file.json` will have everything up to the bytes object that is causing the issue.

In my particular case this was a line obtained through

```
for line in text:
    json_object['line'] = line.strip()
```

I solved by first finding this error with the help of the write_to_file.json, then by correcting it to:

```
for line in text:
    json_object['line'] = line.strip().decode()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while playing with image data. In Python, on the client-side, I was reading an image file and sending it to my server. My server decodes binary data into bytes. So, I just converted my bytes data into a string that solved my error.

```py
image_bytes =  file.read()
data = {"key1": "value1", "key2" :  "value2", "image" : str(image_bytes)}
```

Comment: how did you get it back into `bytes` from a JSON string?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my own by adding `.hex()` at the end of the variable

Example

```
test = "0xfggfddr"
return test.hex()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed the issue by simply casting the line to `str` object before writing to a file.

```py
import json

# Specify the file path where you want to save the JSON data
file_path = f"{machine_number}_can_data.json"

# Write the list to a JSON file
with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json.dump(str(deserialized_value.get('CanMessages')), json_file)
```

Answer (score -2):

#This works for me:

```
thestrvar = base64.b64encode(thevartocode.encode('utf-8')).decode()
```

thestrvar looks like PGh0bWw+DQo8Ym9k...  then

```
rec = {}
rec['myidx'] = thestrvar
print(json.dumps(rec))   #without problems
```