# Sending opencv image along with additional data to Flask Server

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I am currently able to send OpenCV image frames to my Flask Server using the following code

```
def sendtoserver(frame):
    imencoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
    headers = {"Content-type": "text/plain"}
    try:
        conn.request("POST", "/", imencoded.tostring(), headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
    except conn.timeout as e:
        print("timeout")


    return response
```

But I want to send a unique_id along with the frame I tried combining the frame and the id using JSON but getting following error `TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable` does anybody have any idea how I can send some additional data along with the frame to the server.

UPDATED:

json format code

```
def sendtoserver(frame):
    imencoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
    data = {"uid" : "23", "frame" : imencoded.tostring()}
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    try:
        conn.request("POST", "/", json.dumps(data), headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
    except conn.timeout as e:
        print("timeout")


    return response
```

Comment: Could you paste how you have tried to combine your frame and unique ID?

Additionally, if you are explicitly converting your unique_id to bytes, you'll find this error. LEave it to JSON to handle the encoding decoding of things as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682018/typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable

Comment: I have added my json code in the question @RahulRaghunath

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have actually solved the query by using the Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module instead of the http.client module and have done the following changes to my above code.

```
import requests
def sendtoserver(frame):
    imencoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
    file = {'file': ('image.jpg', imencoded.tostring(), 'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '0'})}
    data = {"id" : "2345AB"}
    response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1/my-script/", files=file, data=data, timeout=5)
    return response
```

As I was trying to send a multipart/form-data and requests module has the ability to send both files and data in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try encoding your image in base64 string

```
import base64

with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

And send it as a normal string.

Comment: i am not reading an image directly the image is in the form of numpy array

Comment: encoded_string = base64.b64encode(np_array) Could you try?

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested base64 encoding might be a good solution, however if you can't or don't want to, you could add a custom header to the request, such as

```
headers = {"X-my-custom-header": "uniquevalue"}
```

Then on the flask side:

```
unique_value = request.headers.get('X-my-custom-header')
```

or

```
unique_value = request.headers['X-my-custom-header']
```

That way you avoid the overhead of processing your image data again (if that matters) and you can generate a unique id for each frame with something like the python [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/uuid.html) module.

Hope that helps