# Customized MPII dataset python3 class for pytorch 1.3

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to this kind of image processing work. And I want to build an MPII dataset [described here](http://human-pose.mpi-inf.mpg.de/#download)class for training a pytorch network on it. I tend to work with Python 3.6 and pytorch 1.4

The problem is mainly from that MPII dataset annotation [(download here)](https://datasets.d2.mpi-inf.mpg.de/andriluka14cvpr/mpii_human_pose_v1_u12_2.zip) is in .mat form, which I'm not very familiar with. There are also some implementations I found on Github, like this [deep high resolution net](https://github.com/leoxiaobin/deep-high-resolution-net.pytorch), and also this [Microsoft MPII dataset for python](https://github.com/microsoft/human-pose-estimation.pytorch/blob/master/lib/dataset/mpii.py). The latter is actually adopted in many implementations on the MPII dataset, but it's way too old. It's built with pytorch==0.4.0 and python2, creating a lot of environmental conflict problems.

What I want to do now is just to build a simple pytorch dataset which can automatically extract the joint positions in the 'annotation/' directory, and combine it with the specific image in 'image/' directory. I hope the return value is just a dictionary with these two items, that's all I need.

I also noticed that many researchers tend to convert the original '.mat' annotation file to '.json' format. I think this will make it much easier to operate, but there is some troubles when I'm trying to do this.

```
Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 21:14:29)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> from scipy.io import loadmat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/billy/miniconda3/envs/datasci/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/home/billy/miniconda3/envs/datasci/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/home/billy/miniconda3/envs/datasci/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/billy/miniconda3/envs/datasci/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
  File "/home/billy/miniconda3/envs/datasci/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

I also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682018/typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable) on this site, but I am not sure I understand what is wrong... I 'd appreciate any help very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably would have solved this problem since 9 months have passed, but my simple solution to these kind of environment/installation problems is to utilize virtual or online environments. One example is the [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). You could convert to `.json` format using tools instead of you local environment, and apply the converted file on you ML application.