# Read a gzip file and write into text file

Tags: python, json, gzip

How can I read a gzip file which has JSON content in it and then write that content into a text file.

```py
with open('.../notebooks/decompressed.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    with gzip.open(".../2020-04/statuses.log.2020-04-01-00.gz", 'rb') as f_in:
        data = f_in.read()
        json.dumps(data)
```

Error: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

decompressed.txt image(first 2 lines):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLA5N.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682018/typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: I am little new to this. I tried different codes like json.dump(data,f_out) etc but nothing is working.

Comment: Have the verified the gzipped file is a single JSON serialized file either starting and ending with '[' and ']' or '{' and '}' ??

Comment: The file contains twitter data with structure like:  { "a":value,"b":value} 
 { "a":value,"b":value} 
 { "a":value,"b":value}

Comment: You would use `json.loads`, not `json.dumps` to convert JSON input to a structure. However if you're writing it back out to a file, then you'd need to reserialize it again. So it seems like all you need to do is write `data` to your output file, and not use `json` at all.

Comment: I tried that:
with open('.../notebooks/decompressed.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    with gzip.open(".../2020-04/statuses.log.2020-04-01-00.gz", 'rb') as f_in:
            f_out.writelines(f_in)

But then when I try to load a JSON object using json.loads it doesn’t accept the format.

Comment: Can you run the cmd: `gunzip -c ../2020-04/statuses.log.2020-04-01-00.gz | tail` to see if that works correctly or is there a problem with the file?

Comment: This command is working fine and showing last records of file.

Comment: Is the logfile a single JSON structure or a series of concatented JSON objects on each line? If each line is something like *{'a':value}* then it may be the latter and jsons.load() or json.load() won't work on that directly.

Comment: Please update question with a repesentative snippet of the first and last lines of the decompressed log file.

Comment: I am trying to add the first and last line but it is huge to stackoverflow is not allowing me to do that

Comment: I added a picture for decompressed.txt

Comment: Looks like file is a series of concatenated json objects. Try *for line in fin: obj = json.loads(line)*. Updated answer to address this issue.

Comment: Thank you! The code worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If log content is already json serialized format then just need to write decompressed data as-is.

```python
import gzip
with gzip.open('.../2020-04/statuses.log.2020-04-01-00.gz', 'rb') as fin:
    with open('.../notebooks/decompressed.txt', 'wb') as fout:
        data = fin.read()
        fout.write(data)
```

If file is huge then import shutil module and replace read() and write() with:

```
shutil.copyfileobj(fin, fout)
```

If want to load JSON into a object and reserialize then:

```python
import gzip
import json

with gzip.open('.../2020-04/statuses.log.2020-04-01-00.gz', 'rb') as fin:
    with open('.../notebooks/decompressed.txt', 'w') as fout:
       obj = json.load(fin)
       json.dump(obj, fout)
```

If the log file is a series of JSON structures one per line then try:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('.../2020-04/statuses.log.2020-04-01-00.gz', 'rb') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        # next do something with obj
```

If JSON is too large to deserialize then try [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) to iterate over hugh JSON structures.

Comment: f_out.write(data) is giving error:a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Updated code in answer. if use fin.read().decode() then use "w" mode in output for string content otherwise no decode() on data input and "wb" on output for binary data.

Comment: Updated code is giving this error: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1994) at line  obj = json.loads(json_data)

Comment: If I use shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out) then how would load JSON object while reading the file?

Comment: If `json.loads(json_data)` is failing then data is not valid JSON. Need to print the data to see what it is.

Comment: I understood that I can create a decompressed.txt file using shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out). But in future when I want the read data from decompressed.txt file then would json.loads work?

Comment: Try *obj = json.load(fin)* when loading *decompressed_twitter_lot1.txt* input file.

Comment: json_data = fin.read().decode()
obj = json.loads(json_data).   I tried this after creating decompressed.txt and opening the file again. It is giving Memoryerror with no description. And also obj =json.load(fin) also giving memory error.

Comment: There are modules to stream json files. see [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/); see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files).

Comment: Then I should be creating file with Ijson?

Comment: ijson is to parse huge JSON assuming file is a single JSON structure not series of concatened JSON objects. Can't say much w/o seeing example of the first and last lines of the decompressed input file.